# Placing the blinking cursor between two tags when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this small function that allows a user to select tags. What it doesn't do, it doesn't place the cursor between the two tags (opening and closing) when the button is clicked (Bold, Italic or Underline).

```
function formatText(tag) {
var Field = document.getElementById('some-input');
var val = Field.value;
var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
Field.value = before_txt + '<' + tag + '>' + selected_txt + '</' + tag + '>' + after_txt;
}
```

and:

```
<a href="javascript:formatText('b')" class="small_button">Bold</a>
<a href="javascript:formatText('i')" class="small_button">Italic</a>
<a href="javascript:formatText('u')" class="small_button">Underline</a>
```

PS I tried a couple things none of which worked. For some reason I couldn't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I want. So it's all good.

```
<a class="small_button" id="b"><b>Bold</b></a>
<a class="small_button" id="i"><i>Italic</i></a>
<a class="small_button" id="u"><u>Underline</u></a>
<a class="small_button" id="l">Large</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function addTagSel(tag, idelm) {
 var tag_type = new Array('<', '>');        // for BBCode tag, replace with: new Array('[', ']');
  var txta = document.getElementById('some-input');
  var start = tag_type[0] + tag + tag_type[1];
  var end = tag_type[0] +'/'+ tag +  tag_type[1];
  var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;    // this variable is false in all browsers, except IE

  if (IE) {
    var r = document.selection.createRange();
    var tr = txta.createTextRange();
    var tr2 = tr.duplicate();
    tr2.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
    tr.setEndPoint('EndToStart',tr2);
    var tag_seltxt = start + r.text + end;
    var the_start =  txta.value.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.').indexOf(r.text.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.'),tr.text.length);
txta.value = txta.value.substring(0, the_start) + tag_seltxt + txta.value.substring(the_start + tag_seltxt.length, txta.value.length);

var pos = txta.value.length - end.length;    // Sets location for cursor position
tr.collapse(true);
tr.moveEnd('character', pos);        // start position
tr.moveStart('character', pos);        // end position
tr.select();                 // selects the zone
  }
   else if (txta.selectionStart || txta.selectionStart == "0") {
    var startPos = txta.selectionStart;
    var endPos = txta.selectionEnd;
    var tag_seltxt = start + txta.value.substring(startPos, endPos) + end;
txta.value = txta.value.substring(0, startPos) + tag_seltxt + txta.value.substring(endPos, txta.value.length);

// Place the cursor between formats in #txta
txta.setSelectionRange((endPos+start.length),(endPos+start.length));
txta.focus();
  }
  return tag_seltxt;
}

document.getElementById('b').onclick = function() {
  var tag_seltxt = addTagSel('b');
  return tag_seltxt;
}

document.getElementById('i').onclick = function() {
  var tag_seltxt = addTagSel('i');
  return tag_seltxt;
}
document.getElementById('u').onclick = function() {
  var tag_seltxt = addTagSel('u');
  return tag_seltxt;
}
document.getElementById('l').onclick = function() {
  var tag_seltxt = addTagSel('h5');
  return tag_seltxt;
};
```